# Node-postgres is connecting to localhost instead of AWS Postgres Instance

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, node-postgres

I am new to NodeJS and PostgreSQL, I would like to seek your help regarding to my problem connecting to AWS Postgres Instance. My Nodejs keeps on connecting to my localhost instead of AWS Postgres Instance. Below are my server.js and package.json.

server.js

```
const express    = require('express');
const { Client } = require('pg');
const app        = express();

const client = new Client({
    host: 'db-postgresql.abcdefghi.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port: 5432,
    user: 'db_instance',
    password: 'my_password'
});

client.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('connection error', err.stack)
    } else {
        console.log('connected')
    }
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 5000');
});
```

Package.json

```
{
    "name": "NodeJS PostgreSQL",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "description": "DB Connect",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "nodemon server.js"
     },
    "author": "Mac Pertubal",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
       "express": "^4.16.3",
       "pg": "^7.5.0"
     },
    "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
   }
 }
```

Comment: You should specify the "database" attribute in the Client definition too.

Comment: Hi Mahesh, what do you mean "database" attribute in the Client definition?

Comment: `const client = new Client({
  user: 'dbuser',
  host: 'database.server.com',
  database: 'mydb',
  password: 'secretpassword',
  port: 3211,
})`

Comment: database settings are included already

Comment: To clarify, is this deployed somewhere or are you running it locally? Can you add the error logs to your question?

Comment: My NodeJS is in my local machine and I want to connect it to PostgreSQL in AWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure it out, I forgot to include the database name is my database settings.

Before

```
const client = new Client({
    host: 'db-postgresql.abcdefghi.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port: 5432,
    user: 'db_instance',
    password: 'my_password'
});
```

After

```
const client = new Client({
    host: 'db-postgresql.abcdefghi.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port: 5432,
    user: 'db_instance',
    password: 'my_password',
    database: 'database_name'
});
```

Thank you so much for trying to solve my problem.